# Reading integers from a text file and storing them into a vector using C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, fstream

I am trying to read the last number of each line from a datafile.
When I read the last two digit it converts into string.
My code looks like (upto this point):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string line;
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("prim.txt");
  while (fin) {
    getline(fin, line);
    // cout<<line<<endl;
    string s;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = line.size() - 2; i < line.size(); i++) {
      s = s + line[i];
    }
    cout << s << endl;
  }
  fin.close();
  return 0;
}
```

the textfile from which I want to fetch data is:
[prim.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLRvF.png)

I want to store the last numbers of each line into a vector of int type.

Comment: Place the text of that file into your question. Can't copy paste a picture to test. Maybe if you also described the problem you're having.

Comment: Use `>>` to put the input in separate variables.  There is no need for an inner `for` loop that tries to figure out how many characters to use.

Comment: @sweenish I have given instances of my textfile. I am using a .txt file. Problem is I can't convert the last digit as it is of string class or stringstream

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you please share the code

Comment: @SUDIPTASAMAL What part of "can't copy paste a picture to test" is difficult to understand? If you want help with code, **text** that can be copied and pasted is what's needed, **not** a picture of text. Try to remember that next time you post a question.

Answer (score 1):

If each line of the file contains 3 numbers seperated by space, there is no need for sophisticated parsing via `getline`. Simply read 3 numbers until reading fails and store the last of them in a vector:

```
 std::vector<int> numbers;
 int a,b,c;
 while( fin >> a >> b >> c) numbers.push_back(c);
```

Your code assumes that the last number has 2 digits, which may not always be the case. Also this fails, when there are trailing spaces in a line. Further, reading as string and then converting to `int` is not necessary when you can read `int`s directly. Last but not least, your contidion `while(fin)` is "too late", because the last `getline` will fail when there is no more line to read, but then you still try to process the line (if you wanted to stay with `getline` you could use `while(getline(fin,line))`).

Comment: Thank You @Idclev . It worked. I am new to C++ so I was not good in streamline handling.  Your solution really helped